# Barbecuing in a public park in Athens

Tags: food-and-drink, greece, athens, parks-and-gardens

I will be visiting Athens with my family and I was thinking it would be nice to make a barbeque rather than eating out in a restaurant as we will do every night otherwise.

Does anyone know if it's OK to bring a small barbecue (possibly a disposable one) to a public park (preferably in the Psiri area) and get it on?

Comment: Being Greece at a constant risk for wildfires, I doubt that barbecues would be allowed in their parks. I tried looking up some information but could find none.

Comment: @JoErNanO I'm referring to city parks, not large national parks. "Wildfires" don't happen in city parks

Comment: My assumption is that if there are plants and trees they can burn. Whether it's a city or national park it doesn't matter.

Comment: I doubt it would be appreciated by the local community if you are smoking up their city park with barbecue smoke (however nice it might smell), unless it's a vast expansive open area park. Why not try on the beach? Where those things are quite common and there is virtually no chance of fire. :)

Comment: @Imray Are you sure that wildfires don't happen in city parks? [Have a read on what happened to the Athens suburbs in 2007.](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/europe/6950662.stm)

Answer (score 2):

Going out on a limb here, I would say that **open-fires, and therefore barbecues, are not allowed in public parks in Athens**, or anywhere else in Greece for that matter. This statement is based on the fact that Greece is a country at a constant risk for wildfires during the hot and dry season, which is the peak time for barbecues. I could not find any information (in English) specific to public barbecues. I did however find some statistics behind the wildfire claim. Taking the most recent, most devastating event, [in 2007, wildfires consumed circa 670,000 acres of land](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2007_Greek_forest_fires).

It is also worthy to note that wildfires don't happen only in national parks. In 2007, [several suburbs around Athens were involved in the catastrophic summer wildfires](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/europe/6950662.stm).

This is not to say that the Greeks are not barbecue fanatics. Indeed, most houses with a garden will have either a brick barbecue with an automatic spit-turning system to make [Kokoretsi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kokoretsi), or a dedicated area for a mobile barbecue.